# Is that possible to realize standard NS classes without Foundation Framework in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

Only with standard gcc Objective-C headers.

Most of all I am interesting in arrays and dictionaries.

If that's possible, then which superclasses should be subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easily possible.

Every Objective C object must derive from NSObject (which implement the interface to the runtime system), and NSObject is part of Foundation.

Or, you could try, but you would have to re-implement a lot of low-level things...

Comment: There is <objc/objc.h> standart gcc library for Objective-C where is <objc/Object.h> as incomplete replacement of NSObject

Comment: yeah, you could use GNUStep as a starting point and get their NSObject implementation... it all depends on what your aim is... but again, you would use a part of GNUStep Foundation, don't know if this is what you are aiming to...